# How to share the library resources which are included in "base feature" module

Tags: android, android-resources, android-instant-apps

I have the following structure of android project

- application module
- base feature module
- feature module
- a local library project
- remote libraries

When I try to include the local library project in base feature module with 
api or implementation, the feature either not compiling because of not found resources or throwing the same errors at runtime. 
And now I am wondering is there a point which I misunderstood. The documentation says the base feature module is intended to share the common code and the resources, but it seems it doesn't cover the library cases.

The runtime resource not found errors are thrown when I try to include the same library also in the feature module.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When referecing resources from base module in your feature modules you need to use the full packageName qualifier.

This is because in instant apps they will belong to another name space.

Hence:

`R.id.resource` will point to resources of your feature module
`com.yourdomain.appbase.R.id.resource` will reference resources of your base module